# Decoding error LEDs from "smart" switch

Tags: electrical, smart-switch, troubleshooting

I have a number of HAI/Leviton UPB switches that were installed a number of years ago. They communicate with a central controller for home automation. Leviton no longer makes these switches, though other companies make almost identical compatible hardware.

One feature of these switches is that they contain LED status indicators. By default, when the switch is off the indicator light is blue and when the switch is on the indicator light is off. This is configurable in software, but I have left the default settings. (There is also a red LED, and the two LEDs can turn on together to make magenta.)

One of my switches, model 40A00-1 (15A relay switch), which was controlling ceiling lights and a fan, has stopped working properly. When I try to turn it on, either by pressing the top of the toggle or using the automation controller, it does the following steps in quick succession:

1. Relay clicks on and then immediately clicks off again.
2. LED flashes red once.
3. LED flashes blue once.
4. LED flashes red twice.
5. LED stays solid magenta for a few seconds.

I'm sure that this flash pattern is an error code that could tell me what is wrong with the switch, but there is no documentation that I can find anywhere. I spoke to tech support at one of the companies that makes compatible switches (which use the same blue/red/magenta LEDs) but they do not have any documentation internally about LED flash patterns either.

I'm sure I've seen documentation about this in the past, but I cannot find it anywhere in the piles of old HAI/Leviton documentation that I have.

Does anyone have any documentation that might explain the flash patterns?

Comment: Think if a power off, power on(from breaker) reset does not fix it, might be better to just replace.

Comment: @crip659 I already ordered a replacement, but I still want to see if anyone has any more information.

Comment: Arcane LED sequences are explained in the documentation.  Installation instructions MUST exist, since UL will not approve switches without them.  The instructions define the scope and limit of UL testing.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I have copies (some paper, some PDF) of all the publicly available documentation and all the dealer-only documentation that I could find. The LED sequences are not explained in any of those. The installation documentation describes some uses of the LEDs, but nothing about any codes. I have 'new old stock' spare parts with the installation manuals still in the box, and they say nothing useful.